# Using SSH with SL4A

Tags: android, python, ssh, sl4a

I'm using SL4A (Scripting Layer for Android) in order to integrate python code in Android.

I was wondering if there is any way to connect via SSH inside the code.

I mean, are there any SSH commands that I can use inside the python code?

I know that there is ConnectBot and other apps, but they are external to the SL4A.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to write a SSH client or server in native python.

This can be done with [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), for example. I know of [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/source/browse/python-modules/twisted?name=1b1ea8ea0cd318fd08c0889e0cbebc09d64d09c9&r=8bd1254c181b9a2caba52a9e1b34074b93c77d37) implementation of Twisted for Android, but I have never tried it myself. If you get those two things working, you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://hacklabos.org/2014/06/using-android-to-securely-command-control-your-projects/

> If you make internet connected stuff based on Linux/GNU and own a
>   Android device rejoice! This is a safe(as safe as it gets) way to
>   control your projects, so unlock your home to your friends while miles
>   away, start a car(or don’t), securely wipe all of your disks with one
>   touch, feed the cats, or just turn your lights on and off.